# Relation is surjective iff $I_V=R^T \circ R$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

There is a relation $R$ from $U$ to $V$ for which it is given that it is a function.

How can I prove that $R$ is surjective iff $I_V=R^T \circ R$

Can anyone provide me a hint to solve this problem.

Comment: Please, add what you mean by $R$ is surjective and the definition of $\circ$ you're using. Under most conventions, $R^T\circ R$ will be a relation from $U$ to $U$.

Comment: Here $R$  surjective means that there will be value for every element of $V$ in $U$.   Definition of $\circ$  here is composition

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let $|U|=n$ and $|V|=m$. Then $R: U \longrightarrow V$ can be represented by a binary $n \times m$ matrix $R=[r_{ij}]$. We are assuming that rows correspond to elements of $U$ and columns correspond to elements of $V$ and $r_{ij}=1$ if element $i \in U$ is related to element $j \in V$ via $R$, otherwise $r_{ij}=0$.

Since $R$ is given to be a function, therefore every row of matrix $R$ will have exactly one $1$.

Suppose $R^TR = I_U$ (note: I think you made a typo with $I_V$). Then this means $r$ cannot have a zero column (same as saying $R^T$ cannot have a zero row). In other words, each row of $R$ has exactly one $1$ (from our previous assertion that $R$ is a function) and now each column also has to have at least one $1$. This shows that $R$ must be surjective. Now try the other implication.

Comment: I don't think the question is about matrices.

Comment: @drhab any relation between two finite sets can be represented as a binary matrix (as stated in my solution) . So if your objection is that my proof will not work for infinite sets, then you are right. But the idea used in terms of matrices can be easily generalized to any sets. If the sets were finite then matrix interpretation is totally justified.

Comment: I admit that I was too fast with my comment. Your comment (combined with a closer look at your answer) is valuable in the sense that it opens a way to look at relations. For me this is a new perspective. I have learned something today.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer it is preassumed that the composition of relations is defined as follows:$$\langle x,y\rangle\in S\circ R\iff\exists z\left[\langle x,z\rangle\in R\wedge\langle z,y\rangle\in S\right]$$

First check whether this agrees with your definition.

I suspect that it must be shown that $R\circ R^{T}=I_{V}$ iff $R$
is a surjective function.

We have:

$$\langle x,y\rangle\in R\circ R^{T}\iff\exists z\left[\langle x,z\rangle\in R^{T}\wedge\langle z,y\rangle\in R\right]\iff\exists z\left[\langle z,x\rangle\in R\wedge\langle z,y\rangle\in R\right]$$

So applying that $R$ is a function we find $x=R\left(z\right)=y$. Proved
is now that $R\circ R^{T}\subseteq I_{V}$.

If $v\in V$ then the surjectivity of $R$ assures us that $\exists z\left[\langle z,v\rangle\in R\right]$
wich leads conversely (from right to left) to $\langle v,v\rangle\in R\circ R^{T}$. This shows that $I_V\subseteq R\circ R^{T}$.

Comment: I didn't get your statement that $x=R\left(z\right)=y$ .  And the 2nd proof shouldn't we start from $I_V$

Comment: If $R\subset U\times V$ is a function then for every $u\in U$ there is **exactly one** $v$ with $\langle u,v\rangle\in R$. Notation: $v=R(u)$. That explains $x=R(z)=y$. There were (I repaired) typos in the last line (sorry). I should have started with $v\in V$. Secondly I concluded $\langle z,z\rangle\in R\circ R^T$ but the $z$ must be a $v$. The statement that $\langle v,v\rangle\in R\circ R^T$ for every $v\in V$ is the same as the statement that $I_V\subseteq R\circ R^T$.